# Datetime in PHP return always 1970

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

I have this script in php and the my date always return 1970. I wanted to fix it but I don't know! please someone can help me? Where is marked with "this".

```
<?php

  require_once('banco-dados.php');
  date_default_timezone_set('America/Brasil');

  setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR');
  if (!class_exists('INSERT')){
    class INSERT {
      public function post($postdata) {

        global $db;
    --this    $dataHora = strftime('%d de %B de %G %H:%M', isset($postdata['timestamp_artigo']));
    --this    echo $dataHora;
        $post_categoria = serialize($postdata['categoria']);

        $query = "
                    INSERT INTO artigos (autor_artigo, titulo_artigo, conteudo_artigo, categoria, timestamp_artigo)
                    VALUES ('$postdata[autor_artigo]', '$postdata[titulo_artigo]', '$postdata[conteudo_artigo]', '$post_categoria', '$dataHora')
                    ";

        return $db->insert($query);
      }
    }
  }

  $insert = new INSERT;
 ?>
```

Comment: `isset($postdata['timestamp_artigo'])` will return a boolean `true` or `false` which would correspond to timestamp 0 or 1 both of which are within 1970

Comment: There is no CSS or HTML in this question. I removed the tags

Comment: Yeah... just get rid of the `isset()`. It's just wrong.

Comment: When I removed the isset() appears error:

Notice: Undefined index: timestamp_artigo in /storage/ssd5/570/14963570/public_html/ckeditor/samples/classe-inserir.php on line 12
31 of december of 1970 21:00